# Would it be okay to apply for jobs stating in the cover letter that I'll only be able to do interviews a month after?

Tags: interviewing, applications, vacation

Here is my timeline :

- May 29 : End of current contract and decided not to accept if offered an extension
- June 1-25 : I'll be overseas for a vacation
- June 26 onwards : Back to hometown

Given this, I personally think I could reduce the "unemployment" gap if I started applying early. However, given my vacation schedule, I wouldn't be able to attend interviews in that time period.

These are the options I can see right now :

1. Send applications on late April to early May, and be able to do interviews before vacation starts. If the question *"When will you be able to start?"* comes up, I'll mention my schedule.
2. Send applications during vacation stating that I'll only be able to attend interviews starting on June 26.
3. Both of the above
4. Only start applying when I get back home

Number 4 is the safest, however, I think I'd be spending more time as an unemployed man, and I want to minimize that as much as possible.

What option would be best in terms of employer convenience and minimal unemployment time?

---

Additional information :

During my vacation, I would be able to take phone calls and schedule Skype interviews if necessary.

Comment: What's keeping you from applying for jobs *now* stating that you will be available June 26+ ?

Comment: I don't think you should worry about a job gap if you're applying for contract positions. Taking time off in-between is probably common and they'll think you're well rested for their term and are more willing to work insane hours.

Comment: I think I'd take option 5., start applying even earlier, knowing it may take a while to find a new position.

Answer (score 2):

It depends who you are talking to:

1. Those outfits that actually need someone right away - they will go through their interview and hiring process without you. They'll consider you only in the unlikely event that they kept your initial communication and haven't found anyone suitable.
2. Those outfits don't have an urgent need to add someone but are announcing only because they are constantly on the lookout for someone outstanding - they will hire you fast if you are that someone who they think is outstanding. On the other hand, You may not fit their criteria of what it takes to be outstanding and will continue to announce without hiring anyone for months at a time. On the other hand, if you fit their criteria for outstanding candidates, you can respond to their continuous announcements at practically any time.
3. Those outfits that take weeks to decide whether to phone screen you and have a longer lead time between initial announcement and hiring - the negative impact of your induced delay on them may be limited.

I prefer to deal with prospective employers who think fast, make up their minds fast and act fast when it comes to deciding to go forward with or without me. Your best bet with these prospective employers is to wait until you are fully engaged and ready to start the process. Because they won't wait for you.

You give a more positive impression when you come across to a prospective employer as ready, willing and able to work than as someone who requires that a prospective employer makes a reservation with you several weeks in advance just to see you. If you make contacting you into a complicated process - anything outside of the ordinary may and can be considered complicated - most prospective employers won't bother.

Comment: I don't really agree with this assessment.  If you wait to apply  for a month to prevent companies from dealing with this situation, the fast companies will probably already fill their open positions during that month anyways.  So you're not really better off on that score.  The slower companies may be understanding and wait, but they definitely won't if they don't ever receive your resume.  Besides the fact that a month isn't all that long, and if you do get interview request during that month, it may very well work out that they can't schedule until after anyways.